# Xrdp clipboard stops working after first login - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, xorg

I've installed Xfce and Xrdp on my Ubuntu Server 20.04 with these steps

```
$ sudo apt install xrdp
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
$ sudo apt install xorgxrdp
$ sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
$ sudo systemctl start xrdp            
$ systemctl is-active xrdp 
$ sudo systemctl enable xrdp
$ sudo reboot
```

After reboot everything seemed fined and I was able to login into my server without any problem but after I closed RDP window things seems off a little bit. First of all,my server is pretty strong but restarting `xrdp` is taking like 20 seconds! When I login into the server it takes more than 15 seconds to log into the server and RDP clipboard doesn't work anymore. When I reboot the server everything works fine only first time I log into the server and then It gets messed up. Also when I restart `xrdp` I can't log into the server and as window disappears right after pressing `login` button

Things I've tried so far and didn't work

- Closing **rdpclip.exe** and opening it again
- Adding **Drives** in the RDP **Local devices** section

`cat /var/log/xrdp.log` Output before restarting xrdp

```
[20220313-19:58:14] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:*.*.*.* port 27674
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:*.*.*.* port 3389)
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20220313-19:58:14] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20220313-19:58:14] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:*.*.*.* port 3389)
[20220313-19:58:14] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:*.*.*.* port 27675
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:*.*.*.* port 3389)
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20220313-19:58:14] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20220313-19:58:14] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20220313-19:58:14] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20220313-19:58:15] [INFO ] connected client computer name: V
[20220313-19:58:15] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpdr chan_id 1004 flags 0x80800000
[20220313-19:58:15] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpsnd chan_id 1005 flags 0xc0000000
[20220313-19:58:15] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1006 flags 0xc0a00000
[20220313-19:58:15] [INFO ] adding channel item name drdynvc chan_id 1007 flags 0xc0800000
[20220313-19:58:15] [INFO ] TLS connection established from ::ffff:*.*.*.* port 27675: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
[20220313-19:58:16] [DEBUG] xrdp_00000c0f_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20220313-19:58:16] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20220313-19:58:16] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000409 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20220313-19:58:22] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20220313-19:58:22] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20220313-19:58:22] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20220313-19:58:22] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20220313-19:58:22] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20220313-19:58:22] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20220313-19:58:22] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=3087 connected to X11rdp_pid=1084 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff:*.*.*.* client_port=27675
[20220313-19:58:22] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20220313-19:58:26] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:*.*.*.* port 56248
[20220313-19:58:26] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:*.*.*.* port 3389)
[20220313-19:58:26] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20220313-19:58:26] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20220313-19:58:26] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20220313-19:58:26] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20220313-19:58:26] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20220313-19:58:26] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 3, selected 1
[20220313-19:58:26] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:*.*.*.* port 3389)
[20220313-19:58:26] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: connect failed trying again...
[20220313-19:58:26] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20220313-19:58:30] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: connect failed trying again...
[20220313-19:58:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20220313-19:58:34] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: connect failed trying again...
[20220313-19:58:34] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20220313-19:58:38] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: connect failed trying again...
[20220313-19:58:38] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: error in trans_connect chan
[20220313-19:58:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 43758)
```

### Update

Disabled `channels` in the `xrdp.ini` and now slow login problem fixed but clipboard issue remains since channel is disabled now

```
allow_channels=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been some months now, but in case anybody comes across:

I've found a solution here in this post:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1367195/564580

To sum it up: you have to edit the file

> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

scroll down to the section

> [Channels]

and ensure that those two are set to True:

```
rdpdr=true
cliprdr=true
```

-> cliprdr (clibpoard redirection) and rdpdr (drive redirection)

After restart of xRDP it worked for me and I could exchange data via clipboard in both directions.